# Avoiding catastrophic cancellation in $1-\operatorname{sinc}x$

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point, machine-precision, catastrophic-cancellation

When I try to calculate the function $f(x)=1-\operatorname{sinc}x$
for small values of $x$
I get large relative errors
due to catastrophic cancellation.
I want an accurate way to calculate $f(x)$
without using a series expansion
or an iterative method.
(For my purposes, accurate means
always within about 5 [ULPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)).

I can easily calculate $\operatorname{sinc}x$.
The problem is calculating $1-\operatorname{sinc}x$.
I am looking for a way
that does not simply compute a truncated series
like this:

$$
\begin{aligned}
  f(x)
  &=
  1-\operatorname{sinc}x \\
  &=
  1-\frac{\sin x}{x} \\
  &=
  1-\left(1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-...\right) \\
  &=
  \frac{x^2}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{5!}+... \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Notice the problematic $1-1$
in the second-last line above.

I tried to reformulate $f(x)$
in terms of standard functions
by applying trigonometric identities.
After finding the common denominator $x$,
there are no identities that bridge the $x$
and $\sin x$
terms
in the numerator.

I also tried an approach
similar to [Kahan's $\operatorname{log1p}()$
and $\operatorname{expm1}()$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/185238/918128)
which rely on matching the loss rates
between numerator and denominator,
but I still get large errors.
Maybe that only works
for functions involving $\log$
and $\exp$.

Comment: What if you define $
f(x) = \frac{{x^2 }}{{3!}} - \frac{{x^4 }}{{5!}} +  \cdots 
$ and use it for small $x$ without any preceeding steps involving $1-1$? You can also try a Padé approximation of this convergent series.

Comment: Presumably, the reason you want to avoid series is that you think it takes too long.  Even if your language supports $\sin(x)$ it can take a long time compared to a multiply.  I would just set a threshold and compute $\sinc(x)$ if $x$ greater than the threshold, then use the series when it is less.  If the threshold is small, it won't take many terms of the series to get the accuracy you want.

Comment: @RossMillikan You are correct, yes, but first I want to know if there's a way that uses algebraic manipulation or something more clever like Kahan's trick.

Comment: Instead of the direct series, you can use a Padé approximation, which often converges faster.  It is the ratio of polynomials.  The fact that sinc doesn't have poles makes me suspect that it won't help much.

Comment: @Gary Good points also, but I was hoping for a clever identity or perhaps an error "balancing trick" like in Kahan.

Comment: Disappointing.  It looks just like 1-cos(x) = x^2/2! - x^4/4! + x^6/6! - ... which *does* have a nice formula 2*(sin(x/2)^2).  Is 1-cos(x) just lucky, and 1-sinc(x) is unlucky?

Comment: @DonHatch Indeed. The $x$ denominator seems to prevent a closed-form solution and Kahan's error-matching tricks seem relatively ineffective here. Padé is nice for small inputs but I was hoping for something that holds for all inputs. BTW your page ["The Right Way to Calculate Stuff"](http://www.plunk.org/~hatch/rightway.html) is the inspiration behind this. I've been trying to expand upon your original work. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other contributors, $[2n+2,2n]$ Padé approximants are probably the best approximation.

For example, the simplest
$$f(x)= 1-\frac{\sin x}{x} \sim\frac{x^2(420 -11 x^2)}{60 \left(x^2+42\right)}$$ gives an error of $1.10\times 10^{-8}$ for $x=\frac \pi 6$ and $1.70\times 10^{-12}$ for $x=\frac \pi{24} $.

Comment: Claude Leibovici That works very well for my purposes. Thanks all! RossMillikan, Gary